# Does the Android Studio IDE work on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio on my Windows-7 laptop to develop an Android app.  I am considering upgrading to Windows 10.  Has anyone tried this yet?  Is there anything I should be aware of before I test it?

Comment: I don't know for sure whether this is on topic (don't think it is), but yes - it worked for me :)

Comment: Thank you.  If I remember right, when I was looking on stack overflow last weekend, someone asked this question, and it was down voted and commented as of topic.  Does this question have any place in the Stack Overflow universe?  It's a simple question, whose answers are most valuable from real people who have their own experience.  Where does this question belong?

Comment: I guess it would fit _closest_ here. Not everything fits on Stack though, maybe a reddit or Windows forum, something like that. Edit: It works on my Windows 10 VM as well.

Comment: -1 It'd be very very odd if it didn't work on windows 10..  The question is a little bit strange(me being polite), And if it didn't then that would be mentioned online by somebody that found it didn't work or by some document that said it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is working flawless**
Today I have upgraded my Windows 8.1 pro to Windows 10.I have used Android
studio in Windows 8.1 pro for developing some Android apps,now after changing
the OS also it is working perfectly.I didn't reinstall the software.

Answer (score 2):

My advice -wait. Being cutting edge is one thing, bleeding edge is another.

My experience was not as successful as what Bhargava charan reported in the accepted answer. I get the splash screen then Android Studio disappears from Task Manager. I uninstalled, reinstalled; no use, and cannot find a solution.  BTW, I'm an Android Developer.  Also, VirtualBox does not run a Nexus 7 image; there are network bridge issues which are impossible to resolve. I ended up restoring good'ol Windows 7.